# Upload Wordpress Plugin from ZIP Broken - Returns Symbols Squares & question marks

Tags: plugins, installation, ziparchive

I am trying to upload plugins to my wordpress website. However, when I click "Install Now" my wordpress reloads and prints out a long string of symbols like this:

```
#�EU퇘0'��������q=�y����������{��V�㝀�P(�-���=�p=�%'G�dB���߯��_�����a���k ��� bB#�t!81Q�j@H��L˷֝q&TvR���Q� �����������{3W7�9�<�u����g�:��������.�d|�L$EY�Y��SF� �)T*�2R�ɮ�4C�!
```

Everything else on my site works fine AND I can add plugins by searching and clicking "Install Now."

I guess there's a corrupted file? I have literally no clue and couldn't find anything by googling.

Server details:

1. Wordpress 5.5
2. Hosted on Siteground with Cloudflare
3. Deactivated all plugins and problem still occurs
4. I just pushed from my dev environment to my live (I used Local by Flywheel and WP Migrate DB Pro)

---

Update:
I don't know what happened, but when I checked my installed plugins list ... the plugin was there and not activated.

I guess the "activate now" screen is broken for my wordpress installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin you are using is perhaps corrupted. With 7-zip or similar archivers on your PC, try testing it, or simply extracting it. If you encounter errors, chances are your downloaded plugin is corrupted.

If not, try removing it from your website, then uploading it again using FTP/SFTP.

Otherwise, contact your plugin support.
[image: Test Archive with 7-zip]